# Embedding Github's bug tracker within a website for the users to report directly from within the website

Tags: github

Short question

Can i let my users report issues from within my website using a form and have those issues registered in the Github issue list?

Same could go for enhancements.

I need to show what i've tried so far but apart from Googling i haven't tried anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is officially documented with the GitHub API v3. Reference is [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue). An example is as follows:

First, the POST request:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues
```

Now the query:

```
{
"title": "BUG_NAME",
"body": "BUG_DESCRIPTION",
"milestone": 1,
"labels": [
"Label1",
"Label2"
]
}
```

Comment: Can i have this for users that don't have pull access?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I guess not, it says "Any user with pull access to a repository can create an issue." If you're incorperating it into your website, you could just use your account.