# possible to embed Github list of issues (with specific tag) on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, github-api

Does anyone know of an easy way to embed the list of issues with a specific tag from github onto a website?

This is to embed a list of open bugs on a project website.

Comment: There are several options via the GitHub API. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374778/how-can-i-get-all-the-github-issues-using-github-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374778/how-can-i-get-all-the-github-issues-using-github-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make a query (as in "[Embedding Github's bug tracker within a website for the users to report directly from within the website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023113/6309)").
Then you would generate the html section of your website page which would display the result of that query.

That would use the [GitHub API on Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

```
GET /user/issues
```

Use your account, or an account which sees only the repo(s) you want to list the issues from.

And you can specify the labels

> `labels`  string:     A list of comma separated label names. Example: `bug,ui,@high`

Comment: thank you, that was really helpful! updated the question with the simple code required in case anyone else want to include a buglist on their site.

Answer (score 11):

**Solution using jQuery:**

There is a way to this easily using the github api using just javascript (no need to set up github account, registering api tokens, etc..)

Below is a small demo using jquery to get a list of all the open bugs for a github project (jquery in this example)

```
var urlToGetAllOpenBugs = "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues?state=open&labels=bug";

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(urlToGetAllOpenBugs, function (allIssues) {
    $("div").append("found " + allIssues.length + " issues</br>");
    $.each(allIssues, function (i, issue) {
        $("div")
            .append("<b>" + issue.number + " - " + issue.title + "</b></br>")
            .append(issue.body + "</br></br></br>");
    });
});
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bso6xLee/2/

Comment: Great answer applying the idea I mentioned initially in my answer. +1