# Github how to pull issues to save them for later

Tags: github

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can get GitHub issues from my repos?

I'd like to be able to save them in either a database, or excel, some way that I can format them and they are useful.

I have tried a couple of programs but they are years old and don't seem to do what they say they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GitHub Developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) to issue GET requests for all of your issues. For an example request see [How can I get all the github issues using github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374778/how-can-i-get-all-the-github-issues-using-github-api)