# Is there any way to embed the GitHub Issue Tracker in a webpage?

Tags: github

I'd like to put it in the Progress section of my project's webpage. I tried using an `iframe`, and I tried using `$.load()`, but neither of these work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need all the feature from the native GitHub issues page, you could consider listing those issue to generate your own include/presentation.

See "[possible to embed Github list of issues (with specific tag) on website?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603347/6309)"

[Kasper Souren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245190/kasper-souren) proposes below [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575850/is-there-any-way-to-embed-the-github-issue-tracker-in-a-webpage/33589346?noredirect=1#comment75031924_33589346) the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bso6xLee/2/):

```
var urlToGetAllOpenBugs = "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues?state=open&labels=bug";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(urlToGetAllOpenBugs, function (allIssues) {
        $("div").append("found " + allIssues.length + " issues</br>");
        $.each(allIssues, function (i, issue) {
            $("div")
                .append("<b>" + issue.number + " - " + issue.title + "</b></br>")
                .append("created at: " + issue.created_at + "</br>")
                .append(issue.body + "</br></br></br>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. Now I just need to find a way to parse the markdown properly. Thanks!

Comment: @KasperSouren Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/serverless/scope which is based on serverless configuration, uses Amazon DynamoDB framework and github webhook service to fetch issue stats (open, close, comment, labels, milestones, etc.) and pull requests. It's well documented and allows several configurations, including embedding to one's website. I have just tried it and works well so far!